# mysql select multiply columns from different tables sum vale and group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql select  multiply columns from different tables sum vale and  group by date

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lBH8.jpg)

Comment: what have you done so far ? we are not a free coding company

Comment: You haven't even asked a question.

Comment: Do you want summed by day or by month? Your image indicates per month, so I wrote such answer. Then you accepted an answer that summed per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `union all` and then aggregation:

```
select date, user, sum(vale)
from ((select t1.user, t1.date, t1.vale from t1) union all
      (select t2.user, t2.date, t2.vale from t2)
     ) t
group by date, user;
```

You can add `where user = 'x'`, if you want the results for only one user (either to the outer query or to each subquery).

Answer (score 0):

Extract year and month, and do `union all`, in a derived table. Then `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select y, m, user, sum(vale)
from
(
    select user, year(date) as y, month(date) as m, vale from t1
    union all
    select user, year(date) as y, month(date) as m, vale from t2
) dt
group by y, m, user
```